# How to develop for an interactive kiosk that needs two separate displays. (Preferably in flash)

Tags: flash, multiple-monitors

**Here's the situation:**

- I need to create a game for an interactive kiosk.
- The game is fairly basic, it will most likely be done in flash/AS3 (I believe this
  is the best choice for this kind of game) UNLESS the dual display
  requirement is far easier to accomplish with a different technology.
- The kiosk consists of two displays, both of which need to show
  separate content from within the same game.

**Here's the question:**

How can I (or anyone) create a flash game that utilizes two separate displays for different content? (This is not just a wider field of vision for the game, the two screens will show different things.)

I am asking for a method by which to do this, not for information about coding the game.

**[EDIT] My Idea (probably not the best):**

Design the game on a canvas twice as wide as one of the monitors, then split the canvas in half and code the game to output different things to each half of the screen. Then run the monitors in "extended desktop" mode or something like that, and make sure that the split between the two desktops occurs in the middle of the game canvas.

**[EDIT] The two displays are being fed from the same machine and same graphics adapter. The whole "kiosk" is powered by one single machine.**

Comment: Are there two displays on the same computational unit, or are you referring to two isolated kiosks networked each with independent CPU's?

Comment: @Jason Sturges :  The two displays are being fed from the same machine and same graphics adapter. The whole "kiosk" is powered by one single machine.I just added this to the question to make it easier for others to understand as well.

Comment: Will these flash applications be run inside web browser windows?

Comment: Ditto. Will they be run in a browser or standalone? Does this have to run full screen? Flash might not be able to do what you need if that's the case.

Comment: They will be standalone applications, I can run it in a browser if absolutely necessary but I can't see that being the case, as .flv can run on a machine with flash just fine without a browser?

Comment: Please don't cross post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixel perfect, you could run a split screen display, as you've mentioned.

Another approach could be leveraging Flash LocalConnection:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

> LocalConnection objects can communicate only among files that are
>   running on the same client computer, but they can be running in
>   different applications — for example, a file running in a browser and
>   a SWF file running in Adobe AIR

Via a central controller, synchronization between displays could be maintained for both applications with LocalConnection serving as a communications pipeline.

Or, you could install a host server that both Flash applications communicate through.

If built in Adobe AIR, two applications could communicate peer-to-peer using flash.net.ServerSocket.

Comment: So with LocalConnection you would essentially create a different application for the left screen and the right screen, and then use LocalConnection to fire off the appropriate methods, with the appropriate arguments, at the appropriate times?

Comment: Regardless of implementation, peer-to-peer model would either be independent nodes, or a single master node.  I'd think of it as two views, with a central controller and model.  Unsure what you intend to display, most functionality could be abstracted to a library.  For example, a 3D game could use the exact same code (player and camera), with the other players events dispatched through the pipeline.

Comment: So, essentially I could create a central application model that houses the engine of the game, and then two separate instances of an application that house a library of the necessary methods for the game, then I could use the central controller to fire off the appropriate methods in the two separate applications?

Comment: Sure.  First thing that comes to mind (for me) is virtual reality.  Say, by itself the game is just a terrain with a camera.  When someone joins, an 'add player' event instantiates a player to the scene and binds that players events to the view.  You could launch the app dozens of times, join dozens of players - each person sees their view but gets all the events of the other players on their local instance.

Comment: So essentially a tiny-scale MMO, or I guess just a "multiplayer game". Unfortunately this isn't as cool as that. It's a single player game and the player's view will be restricted to one screen with the HUD, while the other will contain things such as tooltips and maps.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably with some sort of MVC-like design. Separate your game logic from your display (MovieClip instances), and get each screen to render its own view separately.

So in this solution, you'll have some sort of Model class with the actual game data, and each "screen" will poke the data and draw whatever stuff it needs to draw.

This is what MVC is supposed to be good for -- separating concerns like "what is my game (state)" (model) vs. "how do I draw X aspects of my game here" (view).

Comment: That's a great point, I just need some sort of method to sync up the model and the views, but I believe that "LocalConnection" is a good way to do that, as someone at StackOverflow pointed out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The flixel framework has a splitscreen camera feature: http://flixel.org/features.html

Comment: I will keep this in mind if the what Jason suggested doesn't work out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to run the flash application inside a web browser, you might be able to get away with datapassing between Flash and Javascript, and then pass Javascript data between browser windows (and run the browsers full screen for the sake of presentation).

So, basically, Flash on Window 1-> Javascript on Window 1 -> Javascript on Window 2 -> Flash on Window 2